# How to find after Angular upgrade 16: NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a `computed` or an `effect`

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

After upgrading to angular 16, I get the following error:

```
NG0600: Writing to signals is not allowed in a `computed` or an `effect` by default. Use `allowSignalWrites` in the `CreateEffectOptions` to enable these inside effects.
```

Please some help in solving this?
I understand the error, but can not find where. Played around with the rxjs asapscheduler to break up sync behavior that I read about in other posts, but that only moved the problem to other method calls.
I don't use Signal at all yet after the upgrade.
I only use a few ngrx effects during the login and for upading the breadcrumb.

The interesting part of the stacktrace in the browser console that touches my code:

```
.....
    dispatch       @vendor.js:275274
    dispatch       @vendor.js:267855
    getWithQuery   @vendor.js:267952
    getWithQuery   @vendor.js:268740
    byGroups       @apps_portal_src_app_…ent_module_ts.js:98
    (anonymous)    @apps_portal_src_app_…nt_module_ts.js:729
    doInnerSub     @vendor.js:99223
    outerNext      @vendor.js:99218
...
```

And the code part that the stack trace is referring to is:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.assessment$ = this.assessmentService.getAll().pipe(
      mergeMap((assessments) => this.findOrCreateNewAssessment(assessments)), map((assessment) => ({
        ...assessment, groups: this.sort(assessment.groups.map((group) => ({...group, order: group.order.toString()}))),
      })), tap((assessment) => this.initAssessment(assessment)), shareReplay());

    const questions$ = this.questionSubject$.pipe(
      mergeMap((groups) => this.questionService.byGroups(groups.map((g) => g.id))), map((groups) => this.sort(groups)),
      shareReplay());

    this.questionsByGroup$ = questions$.pipe(map((questions) => groupAssessmentQuestions(questions)), shareReplay());

    this.answers$ = questions$.pipe(
      mergeMap((questions) => (arrayIsEmpty(questions) ? of([]) : this.answerService.byQuestions(questions))),
      shareReplay());

    this.rootFormGroup$ = this.questionsByGroup$.pipe(
      mergeMap((questions) => this.answers$.pipe(map((answers) => this.createRootFormGroup(questions, answers)))),
      shareReplay());
  }
```

Details about the variables in the above method:
assessmentService, answerService standard are Ngrx data services that extend from  EntityCollectionServiceBase.

```
private questionSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject<AssessmentGroup[]>(undefined);
questionsByGroup$: Observable<AssessmentQuestionsByGroup[]>;
```

Please help how to find the cause and solve this?
If info/code is missing, please let me know and I will update the question

Comment: Sorry to go off track here. I don't know about your signal issue. But small advice, use effects for side effects, use selectors to narrow data down to what you want. Your code will be clearer and a lot more optimized with selectors

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the following discussion.
It provides more context, why, and a fix.

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/3892#issuecomment-1542791068

Comment: Thanks, I know the GitHub threat, tried several things of it, I understand the concept and context, but how to find the exact cause in my code? As that is what I need before applying the solution ‍♂️

Comment: I suspect `findOrCreateNewAssessment` or other methods are dispatching actions to the store. That is the problem.

Comment: I think it's because we use ngrx-data and did some more debugging, and these are dispatching items to the store. So how to solve that?